# Can't install Steam games for Windows 7 under Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, games, steam

I have had Windows 7 but have now swapped to Linux. I downloaded and installed the Steam Client with no problem. I can login, but I can't download the games I bought before.

They are in my Library but I cant install them as there is no button.

Hope someone can help me.

BTW: I am not a native speaker so I am sorry about mistakes.

Comment: I think not all games are ported to all plattforms so far, what games do you want to install exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Not all games exist on the Linux platform yet.  As such, most of the Windows games probably won't be installed or downloaded because of the lack of a Linux port.

Comment: I have heard that Steam Linux does not show unavailable games in the library, even if they are purchased.

Comment: they dont show them instantly but you can swap between "normal" games and Linux games. If you swap to Games for Windows you can the the games but dont download them. =(

Comment: The point is that you can't install them because they don't have linux ports.  Which is why you can't install the windows 7 games in the linux steam client.